# PHP Passing an instance of a class to another class

Tags: php, oop, class, instance

I'm still kind of new to PHP OO programming techniques and I have a very simple broad question, is it generally bad practice to instantiate a class in a class then pass that instance to another class?

What I want is to be able to create an instance of a specific class I know I will always need through each user request. Class two is more than anything just a helper class, ideally in my application it would be a "loader" that loads the views.

First class which calls the other two classes:

```
require 'classTwo.php';
require 'classThree.php';

class first {
     public $classTwo, $classThree;

     public function __construct() {
          $this -> classTwo = new classTwo;
          $this -> classThree = new classThree;

          $this -> classThree -> displayNum( $this -> classTwo );

     }
}
```

Second class which is the helper class:

```
class classTwo {
     public function returnVal() {
          return 123;
     }
}
```

Third class is the action class where actual work and final display would happen:

```
class classThree {
     public function displayNum( $instance ) {
          echo $instance -> returnVal();
     }
}
```

Overall I just want to know if this is bad practice because I never seen it done before.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Upvoted since it's a good question to ask and I wished I had asked such questions when I first started OOP. Once your familiar with dependency injection which the link in Jaitsu's answer covers well, I recommend taking a look at [Pimple](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/), which is a DI container for all your classes and parameters.

Comment: Thanks @Adam-E I definitely agree and I've worked and read enough PHP OO techniques and never seen the method I was using before and I thought who better to ask than Stack Overflow users which I always find very helpful. I'll definitely look into Pimple thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is good practice to inject any dependent objects, as this allows you to mock quite easily during unit testing.

Generally speaking, if you have `ClassA` and it relies on an instance of `ClassB` to function then you could do something like..

```
$objectB = new ClassB();
$objectA = new ClassA($objectB);
```

Take a look at http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/dependency-injection-in-php/

EDIT: Constructor injection is passing the dependency into the new object's constructor (as demonstrated above).

Setter injection is using a method to set the dependency, and is usually utilised when the dependency isn't critical:

```
$objectB = new ClassB();
$objectA = new ClassA();
$objectA->setObjectB($objectB);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jaitsu, Can you tell me though why is it any better to pass the instance from instantiation rather than from a method.

Comment: @TomBird There are two types of injection, setter injection and constructor injection. Usually if the dependency is optional then you use setter injection, but if your object *must* receive an instance of another object in order to work then use constructor injection

Answer (score 4):

Yes. This would make it a pain to unit test your `first` class because there are dependencies hard coded in it.

Either inject the instances of the classes or inject a factory.