# Passing variables to new objects PHP OOP

Tags: php, oop, variables, object, instance

I was just wondering if the way in which I am passing variables to different objects is the best way of doing things.
So I have a User class which handles all of the information to do with the session. Within that user class is a variable (private) called isloggedon which is a bool set at false by default. Ideally I need to pass that variable onto the usermanage class so I can allow a logged on user to do things such as make new posts.
Here is how I'm doing it at the moment...

```
$user = new User();
$userManage = new UserManage($user->checkLoggedOn());
```

So as you can see I have an instance of user. Within the user class I have a method which returns the isloggedon variable (checkLoggedOn()) so that within the user manage it knows whether the user is logged on or not.

Please put my mind at ease and tell me whether it is the best approach.

Thanks a lot

Comment: For a user manager class I would inject in the user and let the manager ask the user it it is logged in

Comment: @Orangepill Where would the User class come in then though if everything is handled in the UserManager class?

Comment: The user class would still contain "isLoggedOn" and other "user" related variables. The manager would just perform checks and operations that need a "user" in order to be done.

Comment: Constructing with the results of the isLoggedOn call gives the UserManager any indication of who is logged in ... wouldn't be able to manage much with just that.

Comment: @Orangepill Ahh I see so I guess then the usermanager class would only have to check for a null username/userid(possibly) value to determine whether they are eligible to edit posts. Thanks a lot guys :)

Comment: Or call the `checkLoggedIn` method of the supplied user.

Comment: What does `UserManage` actually do?

Comment: @Jack UserManage does all of the management for the user. e.g. Changing password, Changing username, Changing email...

Comment: @Phpthon A similar question has already been asked about [dependency injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444215/php-passing-an-instance-of-a-class-to-another-class?rq=1) which seems to be the real issue.