# How to call different class members in php without conflict?

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance

I have 4 classes, 1 of them is the main class that holds all the general objects.
3 others are situation classes (for the lack of a better word, as they are included in different parts of the script as needed)

I would like to access all three classes' methods and objects from the main class (or at least just the methods) AND access the main class' methods and variables from the other three classes, AND share the access between all the classes, so that I can call any method of any class from any class.

I know I can make the other three classes members of the main class like this:

```
class Main
{
    public $test = 'test';

    public function __construct ($classA, $classB, $classC)
    {
        $this -> classA = $classA;
        $this -> classB = $classB;
        $this -> classC = $classC;

        echo 'Main just got constructed!';
    }
    public function test()
    {
        echo $this -> test;
    }
}
class A extends Main
{
    public function TestA()
    {
        echo 'In Class A';
    }
}
class B extends Main
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'B just got constructed!';
    }
    public function TestB()
    {
        echo 'In Class B';
    }
}

class C extends Main
{
    public function TestC()
    {
        echo 'In Class C';

        // can we access B from here? probably not.
        // would B::TestB() work?

        B::TestB();

        // yes it does.
        // but is there any other way of accessing the method? like $this -> TestB()? apart from extending the B class to C.
        // Is there any downside to using this way of accessing methods and variables? what are the cons?
    }
}
$A = new A;
$B = new B;
$C = new C;
$Main = new Main ($A, $B, $C);

$C -> TestC();
$Main -> classC -> TestC();
```

The first issue with this is, extending the Main class to other classes throws warnings because of the missing arguments for __construct() in the Main class:

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for Main::__construct()
```

The other concern is that if I use this method, then all three classes have to be initiated before the Main Class. But My script requires the main class to be executed at the very start as it establishes connections to mysql and sets environment variables etc. Plus it is not necessary that all three classes will be used at the same time, so in some part of the websites, only one class is required and it is pointless to initiate the other classes in those parts. (I have more than 4 classes, this is just to make things simpler). In that case, how do I make the other classes members of Main after it has been initiated?

Another thing, extending Main class thrice in other classes seems to initiate Main class thrice in separately.. which is resetting the main class' objects and they are not the same when accessed with other classes. I found out about that issue when the test code threw "Main just got constructed!" thrice and it was setting the variables to their default values. How to avoid that? I would like the Main class' variables to have same values across all the other classes.. kind of like global variables.

Comment: I think this question will help you a lot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444215/php-passing-an-instance-of-a-class-to-another-class You are having an issue with class instances. If you just pass them between the different classes and have the code to handle it, you should be able to do exactly why you need. When you instantiate A,B,C a new instance for each classes are created. Just because they extend a common class does not mean they share the same object of that class. It just means that all of them will have the same classes as the extended class unless you override it in the child.

Comment: I think your question is unclear.

Comment: @khuderm I just went through that post and the tutsplus link it had. Its not what I am trying to do exactly. Like I said, Main class is initiated at the very beginning and the other classes are initiated sometime later in the code or in different parts of the websites as required. For example a Posts class is not initiated in the index page or members area. Members class is initiated at members area only. but Main class is required on every page AND its variables need to have the same values throughout the code.

Comment: @felipsmartins umm.. unclear as in? I just want to access all variables and methods of all classes from all classes. I want to make the code modular. so that the Main class doesn't depend upon any other class's existence. Do you get what I'm saying now? for example if Members class does not exist, the Main should not stop working. And when the Members class is required, it should integrate itself to Main class so that  the Main class's methods can call Members Class's methods and vice-verca. Basically two-way communication between all classes. What is the best practice to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you have objects "injected" later or before Main instance is created, maybe you want add um method register in Main class. Also, as long as each class must have access to onother (such as linking) you could add an attribute (maybe $main) with instance of Main class. 
I think it could be useful:

```
<?php

class A 
{
    /**
     * @var Main
     */
    public $main; # Main class

    public function test()
    {
        #$this->main->aInstance->someMethod();
        #$this->main->bInstance->someMethod();  
        // ...  
        return __METHOD__; 
    }
}

class B
{
    /**
     * @var Main
     */
    public $main; 

    public function test()
    {
        return __METHOD__; 
    }
}


class Main 
{
    public $objectPool  = array();

    public function __construct(array $objects = array())
    {
        foreach ($objects as $object) {
            $object->main = $this;
            # add...
            $this->addObject($object);
        }
    }

    public function addObject($object)
    {
        $this->objectPool[ get_class($object) ] = $object;  
    }

    public function getObject($classname)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($classname, $this->objectPool)) {
            return $this->objectPool[$classname];
        }

        return null; # Or raise an Excetion?
    }

    public function test()
    {
        return get_class($this); 
    }
}

$obj  = array(new A, new B);
$main = new Main($obj);

var_dump($main->getObject('B')->main->test());
var_dump($main->getObject('B')->test());
var_dump($obj[1]->main->getObject('A')->test());
```

However, I think these objects know much about each (which is not a good idea - bad design, actually).

Here goes the runnable code: http://3v4l.org/Y19Kr